# multer with sharp resize image(before upload - with toBuffer)

Tags: node.js, express, multer, sharp

I want to upload file with multer and sharp;but resize not work with toBuffer.

here is my codes:

```
sharp(req.file.path)
                 .resize(20,20).toFormat('jpeg')
                 .toBuffer(function (err,info) {
})
```

But if i use with toFile works perfectly.like this:

```
 sharp(req.file.path)
                     .resize(20,20)
                     .toFile("ss.jpg",function (err,info) {
    })
```

Comment: isn't the toBuffer receives a callback with `(err, data, info)` ?

Comment: not get any error:D

Comment: console.log==`<Buffer ff d8 ff db 00 43 00 06 04 05 06 05 04 06 06 05 06 07 07 06 08 0a 10 0a 0a 09 09 0a 14 0e 0f 0c 10 17 14 18 18 17 14 16 16 1a 1d 25 1f 1a 1b 23 1c 16 ... >`

Comment: The purpose of a buffer edit the image more without using disks, it will be stored in memory so chaining edits will be faster. But if that is accomplished then you actually need to write the buffer to file or show it in browser converting it to a base64. check this answer to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503181/how-to-display-a-jpg-image-from-a-node-js-buffer-uint8array