# Unable to display Uint8Array in Electron / Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, buffer, uint8array

I've got a big `Uint8Array` (frame of a camera) encoded in `bgra8` that because of reasons I receive as `Buffer`. I'm adding this information in case someone points out this could be part of the problem:

This is the data when sent:

[image]

This is the code of the conversion of the data when sent:

```
Buffer.from(cam_message.data)
```

This is the data when received in the Electron main process (a different frame):
[image]

In order to display this data I make the conversion explained here: [How to display a JPG image from a Node.js buffer (UInt8Array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503181/how-to-display-a-jpg-image-from-a-node-js-buffer-uint8array)

That is, I send this to the renderer process:

```
Buffer.from(camdata).toString('base64')
```

In the renderer process I receive this as a variable `value`, and I update the `src` of the image:

```
imgeg.src = `data:image/jpg;base64,${value}`
```

But the image is never shown (only is shown the "image" icon, so not a problem with HTML). So could this be a problem with the `bgra8`? Or the `Buffer` or `Uint8Array` data types and my lack of knowledge in how to use them?

Comment: You said the data is in `bgra8` format. However, you are trying to load it as if it were in JPG format. You need to draw the pixels on a canvas instead

Comment: Hi @AndrewParks, could you be a bit more specific or send me a link? I spent some time looking for displaying ```bgra8``` in ```javascript``` and couldn't find a thing.

Comment: You have to read each pixel in the array, and draw a pixel of each color on a javascript canvas. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899799/whats-the-best-way-to-set-a-single-pixel-in-an-html5-canvas

Answer (score 0):

As @AndrewParks told me, it was a problem with how I tried to display this image as a `jpg` instead of treating it as `bgra8`, which was the correct encoding. This is the code I wrote:

Instead of a `Buffer` now I convert the data to `Uint8Array` again once I receive it and before sending it to the renderer process:

```
Uint8Array.from(camdata.data)
```

In the renderer process I receive this as a variable `value`, and I use a `<canvas>` instead of an `<img>`:

```
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canv');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
      var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
      var id = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
      var pixels = id.data;

      for(var i=0; i<pixels.length; i=i+4){
          pixels[i] = value[i+2];
          pixels[i+1] = value[i+1];
          pixels[i+2] = value[i];
          pixels[i+3] = 255;
      }
      ctx.putImageData(id, 0, 0);
```

See: [What's the best way to set a single pixel in an HTML5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899799/whats-the-best-way-to-set-a-single-pixel-in-an-html5-canvas)